# Transforming from String to byte Array to file

Tags: java, fileoutputstream

I received an image data as String in response which i transform to byte[] and then write into pdf file but not able to open in pdf as it says either corrupt file or not decoded correctly. When I open with the text, i see exactly the same string data which i received in response. Please see below and correct me.

```
String response = "AAAAAAAAA......AAAAA==";

/*byte[] imageByteArray = response.getBytes(); */
 /*  decode string */
byte[] imageByteArray = Base64.decodeBase64(response);

FileOutputStream imageOutFile = new FileOutputStream("D:/output.pdf");

imageOutFile.write(imageByteArray, 0, imageByteArray.length);

imageInFile.close();
```

Please find: [enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1nSorCYDNj8NWRrLWFYbXBjTTg/view?pli=1)

Comment: You need a library to do this, because PDF has its own internal format.  Have a look at iText or similar libraries.

Comment: if you get an image as response, you should save it as it is, an image and not as pdf.

Comment: also note that `==` at the end of the string smells like base 64 encoding

Comment: Both Tim, and Jens make point. Do you need to save an image as a PDF should be your first question. If you can answer that, and the answer is yes, you should look into some library to convert an image to PDF file. You cannot just go, save anything in a file with extension .pdf and expect that file to be successfully open in PDF reader application.

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaPDF/article.html

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  I have tried to convert into jpg/png but failed to do so.

Comment: As @RC mentioned, your raw data appears to be Base64 encoded.  Please try decoding it using the Apache IO utils library, and then save as an image.

Comment: @RC. I have also tried after decoding the data but no success.

Comment: Can you share the whole string? What does it look like? Or better, dump the content into a file and share the file.

Comment: @RC. ok sure... i am sharing the data. I have also mentioned the code for decoding the data and streaming to file, Please see above

Comment: @RC. please get the xml file and get the data of `OutboundLabel`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the posted data is not an image, I don't see how a bunch of "A"  followed by "==" could be image data. You should ask the data provider how to interpret the data

Comment: Thanks @RC. yes you are right. there is some issue at the the server side for which i reported the same.

Answer (score 0):

writing to PDF cannot be done directly using java.io classes.
You need to use APIs like iText to write data to PDF.

Please check below URL:
http://itextpdf.com/

Comment: it's successfully written a pdf file using output stream in my case.